# Warning: Undefined array key - PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Estoy intentando generar un reporte utilizando FPDF para un resultado de un sistema de encuesta realizado en PHP

pero al generarlo me sale el siguiente error

[image: Warning: Undefined array key]

Este es mi código

```
<?php

    require "FPDF/fpdf.php";

    class PDF extends FPDF
    {
        function Header()
        {
            $this->Image('../imagenes/Logo-fis.png', 5, 5, 20 );

            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            $this->Cell(30);
            $this->Cell(120,10, 'Reporte De Usuarios',0,0,'C');
            $this->Ln(20);
        }

        
        
        function Footer()
        {
            $this->SetY(-15);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','I', 8);
            $this->Cell(0,10, 'Pagina '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C' );
        }       
    }
    //Agregamos la libreria FPDF
    require('../conexion.php');

    $id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta'];

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $resultados2 = $con->query($consulta);

    while ($row2 = $resultados2->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $id_pregunta = $row2['id_pregunta'];

        $query = "SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta, preguntas.titulo,COUNT('preguntas.titulo') as count, opciones.valor FROM opciones INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = '$id_pregunta' GROUP BY opciones.valor ORDER BY preguntas.id_pregunta";
        $resultados = $con->query($query);


        $pdf = new PDF();
    
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        
        $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode('Código'),1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode('Clave'),1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Nombres',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Apellidos',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Correo',1,1,'C',1);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

        $i = 1;
        while ($row = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {

            $pdf->Cell(50,6,$row['count'],1,1,'C',1);
            $i++;
        }/*87*/


        $opciones = $i - 1;

        $pdf->Cell(50,6,$opciones,1,0,'C',1);

        $pdf->Output();

    }


 ?>
```

Cual podría ser el error?

Comment: cual es la linea 33?

Comment: ¿Estas agregando ese índice en la URL? `.../reporte2.php?id_encuesta=2` o si es API, en el GET? Debes considerar todas las condiciones, por ejemplo, si alguien escribe la url sola sin pasarle un parámetro GET, o si el mismo es incorrecto.

Comment: asi leyendo por encima, parece que te dice el error en el $_GET['id_encuesta']; esto puede ser porque esta pagina se ejecuta desde un formulario que no envia ese dato, pues intentas acceder al indice y te da error. Desde donde llamas a reporte2.php?

Comment: Es muy probable que no estés recibiendo el valor de lo que corresponde a $id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta'];  y lo interpreta como te lo esta indicando, valida que lleve algún valor y luego proceda a generar el PDF.

Comment: La línea 33 hace referencia a esta parte del código ```$id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta'];```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, cuando tenemos un error como este y lo queremos resolver hay que analizarlo bien. Con esto tenemos que variable es, de que tipo, y en que línea... ya con esto deberías poder encontrar solo el problema.

```
Warning: Undefined array key ... on line 33
```

Linea 33, ¿Cuál es la línea 33 de este código?
Al copiar y pegarlo, [la línea 33 cae en un sector en blanco](https://i.gyazo.com/fcabd9363c884b801392af1459fae7e0.png) por lo que no es posible determinarlo para nosotros. En este caso debes decirnos cual es la línea 33.

Ahora, el tipo es `array` y sabemos que la clave es `id_encuesta`, por lo que el primero en tener ese id como un array, es el `$_GET`.

Puedes siempre analizar que un GET se haya cargado, antes de realizar cualquier cosa con el, si el GET no se ha cargado, nunca habrás rescatado el valor.
Este es un ejemplo de como revisar esto:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id_encuesta'])){
    $id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta']; //Se carga en una variable
    //podemos continuar la ejecución, recordar analizar que no este vacía
}else{
    //Acá anunciamos que ha ocurrido un problema al obtener el dato.
    echo "Problemas con el recibo de $_GET['id_encuesta']";
}
?>
```

Comment: la línea 33 hace referencia a esta parte del código  ```$id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta'];``` he probado lo que me dijiste pero sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: Te dije como revisar si la variable se carga o no... no has respondido si la variable se carga o no...

Comment: He revisado con tu código y en efecto la variable no se carga

Comment: En efecto entonces, es un problema de envió y recibo, corrige agregando como envías la variable por medio de get.